# What is the derivative of $(\mathbf{I} - \mathbf{x x}^T) \,\mathbf{x}$ with respect to $\mathbf{x}$?

Tags: matrices, derivatives, vectors, matrix-calculus

> What is the derivative of $(\mathbf{I} - \mathbf{x} \mathbf{x}^T ) \, \mathbf{x}$ with respect to $\mathbf{x}\in \mathbb{R}^n$?

I think the result should in $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$,
but I failed when calculate the first part.

The first part $\mathbf{I} - \mathbf{xx}^{T}$ is a $n\times n$ matrix and the derivative belongs to $\mathbb{R}^{n^2\times n}$.

So, is there anything wrong with the process?

Answer (score 3):

The mapping $f(x):=(I-xx^T)x$ is a mapping from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^n$. It can be simplified to
$$
f(x) = (I-xx^T)x = x - |x|_2^2 x.
$$
Its directional derivative at $x$ in direction $h$ is given by
$$
f'(x;h) = h - |x|_2^2 h - 2x^Th\cdot x\\
=h - |x|_2^2 h - 2xx^Th\\
=(I-|x|_2^2 I -2xx^T)h.
$$
hence the derivative is given by the matrix
$$
f'(x) = I-2xx^T- |x|_2^2 I,
$$

Comment: Thanks for your kindly reply. But what if `$f(x) = (I - xx^T)(x + a)$`, where `a` is also a vector.

Answer (score 1):

Define the variables 
$$\eqalign{
  A &= (I-xx^T) &\implies dA = -(dx\,x^T+x\,dx^T) \cr
  b &= (x+a) &\implies db = dx \cr
}$$
Then write the function and apply the Product rule to find its differential and gradient as 
$$\eqalign{
 y &= Ab \cr
dy &= A\,db + dA\,b \cr 
   &= A\,dx - dx\,x^Tb - x\,dx^T\,b \cr
   &= A\,dx - x^Tb\,dx - xb^T\,dx \cr
   &= (A - (x^Tb)I - xb^T)\,dx \cr
\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} &= A - (x^Tb)I - xb^T \cr
}$$

Comment: Thank you so much, it seems more clear than using the chain rule. :)